# .has-global-padding not added to .is-root-container in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have some issues with .has-global-padding not being added to is-root-container.

In theme.json I have the follwing settings:

```
"settings": {
    "useRootPaddingAwareAlignments": true,
    "layout": {
      "contentSize": "840px",
      "wideSize": "1100px"
    }
},
"styles": {
    "spacing": {
      "blockGap": "2rem",
      "padding": {
        "top": "1rem",
        "right": "1rem",
        "bottom": "1rem",
        "left": "1rem"
      }
    }
```

Even having the padding defined, the has-global-padding class is not added to is-root-container.

Any idea what I am missing?

Thanks,
Aldo

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. If I activate twentytwentythree, .has-global-padding gets added to .is-root-container, but when I reactivate my custom theme, it gets removed. I tried mirroring the entire theme.json file from twentytwentythree exactly on my theme, and the problem persists. For now, I'm going to have to add custom CSS to mimic what should be the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I've been using to add .has-global-padding and .is-layout-constrained (and remove .is-layout-flow) from .is-root-container:

```php
/**
 * Apply ugly hack to set correct root editor container classes
 * 
 * Setting settings.useRootPaddingAwareAlignments to true and settings.layout.type to
 * "constrained" should result in these classes being added properly, but it does not.
 * So, we add them manually. This allows front- and back-end layouts to match, since
 * both containers are wrapped with the same classes.
 * 
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75912533/has-global-padding-not-added-to-is-root-container-in-wordpress
 */
add_action('admin_footer-post.php', 'aquamin_root_editor_container_fix'); // Fired on post edit page
add_action('admin_footer-post-new.php', 'aquamin_root_editor_container_fix'); // Fired on add new post page
function aquamin_root_editor_container_fix() {
    echo "<script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            var rootContainer = null;
            var editorCanvas = document.querySelector('iframe[name=\"editor-canvas\"]');
            if (editorCanvas) {
                rootContainer = editorCanvas.contentWindow.document.querySelector('.is-root-container');
            } else {
                rootContainer = document.querySelector('.is-root-container');
            }
            if (rootContainer) {
                if (!rootContainer.classList.contains('has-global-padding')) {
                    rootContainer.classList.remove('is-layout-flow');
                    rootContainer.classList.add('has-global-padding');
                    rootContainer.classList.add('is-layout-constrained');
                } else {
                    console.log('The theme is now adding .has-global-padding properly: you may remove this patch.');
                }
            }
        });
    </script>";
};
```

You can just add that to functions.php. it works great: now the block editor shows the correct left/right padding, and .alignfull blocks within it properly use negative margins to go full width. Still, it's unfortunate to need to use a hack like this...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because Twenty Twenty-Three uses HTML templates, and in `single.html` it has:

```html
<!-- wp:post-content {"layout":{"type":"constrained"}} /-->
```

When "Use theme styles" is checked in Gutenberg, this template is used.